# Drupal 8 Theme CSS not attached

Tags: drupal-8, drupal-theming

I have the following theme configuration ...

**mytheme.info.yml**

```
name: MyTheme
type: theme
description: Theme based on <a href="http://emulsify.info">Emulsify</a>.
base theme: stable
core: 8.x

# Libraries (These are loaded on every page. Use https://www.drupal.org/developing/api/8/assets#twig whenever possible.)
libraries:
  - mytheme/global
```

**mytheme.libraries.yml**

```
global:
  version: VERSION
  css:
    theme:
      dist/style.css: {}
```

That stylesheet is not being attached to my pages. I tried adding the same stylesheet onto the Bartik theme in the same way and it worked fine. Any thoughts on what I'm missing or how to track this down?

Thanks!

**EDIT:**

I'm getting "Notice: Array to string conversion ... " I believe on this line that gets generated in the file "**sites\default\files\php\twig\5c785ff00bd6e__html.twig_0yYIGbLfvl1AKm7qslTBE8W-Z\Fay9SGEvR_arQ_YULxnlOBW1yidhbxKLSR3KrUE5-bc.php**":

```
echo $this->env->getExtension('Twig_Extension_Sandbox')->ensureToStringAllowed($this->env->getExtension('Drupal\Core\Template\TwigExtension')->escapeFilter($this->env, ($context["page_top"] ?? null), "html", null, true));
```

My **_html.twig** file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html{{ html_attributes }}>
  <head>
    <head-placeholder token="{{ placeholder_token|raw }}">
    <title>{{ head_title|safe_join(' | ') }}</title>
    <css-placeholder token="{{ placeholder_token|raw }}">
    <js-placeholder token="{{ placeholder_token|raw }}">
  </head>
  <body{{ attributes }}>
    <a href="#main-content" class="visually-hidden focusable">
      {{ 'Skip to main content'|t }}
    </a>
    {{ page_top }}
    {{ page }}
    {{ page_bottom }}
    <js-bottom-placeholder token="{{ placeholder_token|raw }}">
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had started my theme on another, clean install of Drupal 8 and then moved it over to my working installation. I didn't even think about the fact that I already had a module in that install that had the same name as my theme. Rename the theme, problem fixed.

Leaving this here as a warning to others - do not use the same name for a theme and a module. Should probably be obvious, but maybe you end up here anyway like I did.

Comment: Yes this is the drupal core issue, that is known for almost a decade now :)
https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/371375